# How to use tf.keras.preprocessing.image.smart_resize(image, IMAGE_SIZE)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I use `image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.smart_resize(image, IMAGE_SIZE)` in processing functions (`tf 2.3.0`).

```
def process(file_path, is_train=False):
    
    # read file and decode image
    image = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=CHANNELS)
    
    if is_train:
        # augment image
        image = tf.image.flip_left_right(image)
    
    # resize image
    image = central_crop(image)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, IMAGE_SIZE, method='lanczos5')
#     image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.smart_resize(image, IMAGE_SIZE)

ds_val = list_ds_val.map(process, num_parallel_calls=AUTO).batch(BATCH_SIZE).prefetch(AUTO)
```

But get an error:

```
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-29-4f70d10b9b77>:14 process  *
        image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.smart_resize(image, IMAGE_SIZE)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/image.py:126 smart_resize  **
        if target_ratio < img_ratio:
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:877 __bool__
        self._disallow_bool_casting()
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:490 _disallow_bool_casting
        self._disallow_in_graph_mode("using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool`")
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:479 _disallow_in_graph_mode
        " this function with @tf.function.".format(task))

    OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.
```

Comment: Could you share a bit more code, how do you get the `image` and how are you calling this function?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known [bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41501), which makes `smart_resize` non-compatible with `tf.data.Dataset` in `tf 2.3`.

[PR](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/41502) was created to address this issue, bug has been already fixed and it's merged to master.

> Rewrite the crop part for `smart_resize` to avoid if-else. The target height (width) is always the smaller of original height (width) or the height (width) calculated from width (height).
> This change makes `smart_resize` compatible with `tf.data.Dataset`.

**Pull the latest [Tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) (`tf-2.3`) and it should work.**

From tf-2.3 latest [release-note](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v2.3.0):

> Introduces experimental support for Keras Preprocessing Layers API
> (`tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.*`) to handle data
> preprocessing operations, with support for composite tensor inputs. Please see below for additional details on these layers.

Note: For official documentation, refer [api_docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/smart_resize).